# Magento showing top menu twice

Tags: magento

Magento is showing the top (categories) menu twice after upgrade, see screenshot.

It seems to me that the `top.phtml` is being executed twice by the line `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>` in the file `header.phtml`.

I have tried switching to the default code ( ie from the base/default theme) for each of these files but I get the same result. I have also checked the backend admin and when I pick a category and select 'NO' from `Include in Navigation Menu` the category disappears from BOTH iterations of the menu.

Can anyone suggest a possible solution or course of action.

Magento Community Edition 1.7.0.0

[image]

**EDIT:** I have discovered that setting **system>config>design>themes>layout** to the original ( downloaded ) theme as opposed to my own makes the problem go away, however I have layout mods I need to keep so I still need to isolate the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this problem manifested itself on my site after upgrade from 1.6 to 1.7.0.2.

1.6 used top.phtml to render the menus.  I had customized top.phtml and included changes in my custom theme via mytheme/layout/catalog.xml with

```
        <reference name="top.menu">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

1.7.0.2 seems to now use a module topmenu.phtml to render the menu.

So I removed my customization by removing the call in catalog.xml and added my customizations back into topmenu.phtml.

No more double menus!

Comment: works great, thank you! had also a fresh updated magento instance with custom template (from 1.4.1) :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after an upgrade from 1.6 to 1.7 and was able to resolve it by removing following code

```
<reference name="top.menu">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

at the beginning of

```
/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/catalog.xml
```

In the beginning of the original 1.6 file this code was mentioned (and therefor also copied in my theme) but in the original 1.7 file this code seems to be removed.

Hope this helps!?

Answer (score 1):

Compare the current page.xml layout with the previous or base and see if you are perhaps adding the top menu again.
The navigation is defined in this block in page.xml

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Have a look in your design folder for the top.menu or catalog.topnav strings and see if they are reproduced anywhere else.

Comment: Also as is customary with Magento, de-cache everything.

Comment: I checked for page.xml but neither the installed theme or my own mod version used page.xml, so it appears to be coming from `base/default/layout/page.xml` In that file there is a piece of code `<block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label"><label>Navigation Bar</label><block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/></block>` and within that removing `<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>` gets rid of the second menu but why is the core file rendering the menu twice.

Comment: getting rid of the entire block removes both menus. BTW I have disabled and flushed cache

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused as to what could be causing this. That is the block I meant. Is there a local.xml in your theme?

Comment: Also put a var_dump(\_\_FILE\_\_) into the page/html/topmenu.phtml just to double check that the template itself is getting called twice.

Comment: local.xml : yes, one in the original theme and another modified version in my own theme; but I disabled both and the problem persists ... I tried putting var_dump(__FILE__) into page/html/topmenu.phtml but I got nothing out of it, ie not an error, just it didn't output anything, actually not sure what you'd be expecting to see here TBH. I am going to switch the display back to the default theme and see if the problem persist there.

Comment: did you mean to put the var dump in template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml by any chance ... I don't understand magento very well at this stage but I cant see that topmenu.phtml is actually being used for anything ... anyway when I put the var_dump in top.phtml I get the same output twice

Comment: I have discovered that setting system>config>design>themes>layout to the original ( downloaded ) theme as opposed to my own makes the problem go away, however I have layout mods I need to keep so I stil need to isolate the problem - I will update the question above and I will try to remove all the mods and add them back one at a time and see where that gets me.

Comment: Tracked it down to catalog.xml ... my theme had `        <reference name="top.menu">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
        </reference>` in there which I'm certain must have been in the copy of the original base file ... ( so I guess I'm suggesting that the latest version of Magento must not need this code or something ) , but of course I could easily be wrong ... anyway I don't really care as removing it got me what I wanted. Thanks for your help, you saved me a lot of time so I'm awarding you the accepted answer.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found the problem. Most of the time these problems can be tracked down to layout xml problems. I don't think that block is normally in catalog.xml so it may have been added by the theme author. I'll double check a blank version of Magento tomorrow.

Comment: See that's what's confusing me. The downloaded theme didn't have a catalog.xml file in it at all, I added that myself (to my own modified version of the theme ... ie it was a copy of the original core file ), but I don't recall adding this particular bit of code to it, or having any reason to add this ... and also it wasn't rendering double till the update.